# rebuild all indexes in all tables but need to exclude a certain tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

I was looking the way to rebuild all indexes in all tables and I found an script that does it, but i would like to get 6 specific tables for not getting index rebuild.

How can I accomplished that with the below script. In SQL I can add a where condition like : where table not in ('table1','table2').

```
USE sparcsn4prod

DECLARE @TableName varchar(255)

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='base table'


OPEN TableCursor 


FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Tablename
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0

BEGIN

DBCC DBREINDEX(@TableName,' ',90)

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Tablename

END

CLOSE TableCursor

DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Rebuilding indexes is a product specific functionality. That code as well.)

Comment: microsoft sql 2012

Comment: This is a very simple cursor, I'd recommend trying to understand the code you will use on your server before executing.

Comment: How can you accomplish this? Yes - by adding a where clause. But don't reinvent the wheel. Ola has written an [intelligent set of db management procedures](https://ola.hallengren.com/) that many people use.

Answer (score 2):

Except the fact that I think that cursors are one of the worst inventions in the SQL Server Universe (at least according handling and performance), you can simply extend your cursor definition in order to filter the unwanted tablenames:

```
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='base table'
  AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN ('table1','table2','table3')
OPEN TableCursor
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than re-invent the wheel, I suggest you consider using [Ola Hallengren's Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html). This allows one to exclude specific databases, tables, or indexes from normal index maintenance.

The `dbo.IndexOptimize` parameter value below will optimize all indexes except for the specified table.

```
@Indexes = N'ALL_INDEXES, -YourDB.YourSchema.YourTable'
```